# How to synchronize only part of project?

Tags: git, deployment, aptana3

I have a web project in Aptana Studio 3 with a git repository. Unfortunately, when it was created, it brought in all the folders like mail, etc, tmp. What's the best way to only deploy my public_html folder only to the web? Should it be the only folder in my git repository and Aptana project, or is there a way to cloak entire folders so I can just deploy the public_html to the web?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GIT repository is for stuff that should be source controlled.  Since mail, etc, tmp shouldn't be under source control, the solution to your problem is to get them out of the repository.  It appears that your GIT repository could be at the wrong level.  So you have two options:

1) Abandon the existing GIT repository and create a new one in public_html

```
$ cd /path/to/public_html
$ git init; git add -A; git commit 'Initial publc_html'
$ rm -rf ../.git
```

2) Keep the existing GIT repository but remove mail, etc, tmp.

```
 $ cd /path/to/public_html/..
 $ tar cf keepers.tar mail, etc, tmp  <others>
 $ echo "mail/\netc/\ntmp/\n" >> .gitignore
 $ git rm -r mail etc tmp     # <= careful
 $ tar xf keepers.tar
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I kept the existing GIT repository. In Aptana, I opened Publish => Deployment Settings and changed the remote path from / to /public_html.

Answer (score 0):

Use [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) to extract the relevant part of the repository (with history) to produce another repository, then push it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.gitignore` file. Just add unnecessary for deployment files and folders there. 
It's not a good practice to store passwords, keys and your environment settings(like local db settings, etc.) under git too.

Look at good examples for your projects [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore).